# Model added by south migration doesn't show in production admin site

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I'm trying to add a new model to an pre-existed app on my production site with the following steps:

1. Adding a model
2. Add `admin.site.register(<ModelName>)` in the app's `admin.py`
3. `./manage.py schemamigration <appname> --auto`
4. `./manage.py migrate <appname>`

   The above steps work on my dev machine (with SQLite3), so I continued with
5. Upload the codes (`models.py`, `admin.py` and the migration file) to the production machine
6. Repeat step 4. on the production machine (with MySQL)
7. `service uwsgi restart`

The migration works. I can see the new table(s) in the database, and I can use the model correctly (with `./manage.py shell` on the production machine). The only problem is that the model is not shown in the admin site. I tried:

- Dev site + dev database => Works.
- Production site + production database => Can't see the model in Admin site.
- Dev site + production database => Can't see the model in Admin site.

Is there something I missed? Thanks.

Comment: That all looks right to me. Could it be a caching issue?

Comment: If that's the case, I can't find a way to "uncache" it. I just rebooted the server and it doesn't work.

Comment: The south migration worked. So that's not the problem. The updated admin.py is not being loaded. You could test this by putting some logging inside it? As to why it's not being run... What other settings do you change between dev and production?

Comment: The new `admin.py` is read - at least on the dev machine. What I don't get is that if the migration worked, why I see the correct admin page on my dev machine **only when I user my dev database**. The only difference between those settings is the `DATABASES` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

After some `pdb` play-around I finally located the problem. It's about permissions. I set the permissions differently on my dev and production databases -- I am a superuser using the dev database, but only a staff on the production database, for whatever reason. The new model I added had its permission set to only visible to superusers, so obviously I can't see it on the admin page. Everything works after I promote myself.